# Anuglar material autocomplete functionality to filter out non numeric values

Tags: angular, angular-material, autocomplete

I have a requirement for an autocomplete that requires the type ahead functionality to ignore characters that are not numeric. For example in the dropdown we have values 123/12R34, 123/13R45. We should be able to bring up the value 123/12R34 as we typed in 12312. What we currently have is as the search stops at 123 as 123/ has "/" character. We use angular autocomplete. Below is the code

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="question.questionType === 'AUTOCOMPLETE'">
    <mat-form-field
      ><input
        matInput
        name="{{ question.id }}"
        [ngClass]="question.cssClass"
        [ngModel]="answers[question.id]?.answer"
        (ngModelChange)="
          setFilteredOptionsbyQuestion(question, $event) &&
            (answers[question.id] = answers[question.id] ? answers[question.id] : {}) &&
            (answers[question.id].answer = $event)
        "
        (keypress)="onKeyPress($event)"
        type="text"
        [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      /><mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option
          *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions[question.id]"
          value="{{ option.value ? option.value : option.label }}"
          >{{ option.label }}</mat-option
        >
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>

 setFilteredOptions = () => {
this.questions.forEach(q => {
  if (q.optionGroup && q.questionType === 'AUTOCOMPLETE') {
    this.filteredOptions[q.id] = this.groupOptions[q.optionGroup] ? this.groupOptions[q.optionGroup] : [];
  }
});
```

};

Does anyone know how to implement it based on the code snippets.